# How far is 1 meter?

Tags: torchlight-2

How far is 1 meter in Torchlight 2 represented on screen?  How many meters is it from the character to the sides of the screen for each aspect ratios?

[image]

Comment: What do you even mean by that? 1 meter is always 1 meter. Are you asking about how many pixels on the screen 1 meter will translate to in their engine?

Comment: @korona I meant in game wise

Comment: I still don't understand. 1 meter is one meter. It's a unit of length. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @yx. About 1.0936133 yards or 3 feet and 3/8 inches.

Comment: @kronoa how far on my screen does 1 meter represent

Comment: @korona You are comically missing the point.  A meter stick isn't going to help anyone gauge distances **in Torchlight 2**.  Maybe a better question for the OP to ask is to provide a in-game reference, like "how many meters is it from the target dummy in Estherian Enclave to the fishing hole"?

Comment: My comment made sense before the question was edited. The question is completely valid as it is stated now.

Comment: I apologize, my comment above was meant to be a reply to the rather useless one from @Krazer, not you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On the *Arcane Statistics* screen (bottom of the left character information screens, press <kbd>J</kbd> by default), you can see the **Adjusted Range** of your currently equipped weapon(s) once you have expanded the *Right/Left Hand Weapon* section.

Here is the display for one of my Embermage's wands (which apparently has a range of 7.2m):

[image: Screenshot showing the 7.2m range of my Embermage's wand as shown on the in-game character info screen]

Using this information you should easily be able to work out how much that +0.67m range improvement has actually extended the range of a specific weapon by, which is what I assume you *really* want to know here.

You can also get a good visual ideal of how distance translates on screen by firing a weapon of known range from a standing position and seeing how far across the screen it's shots go. Of course, this assumes the "adjusted" range is what it will actually fire at the moment.

And, if we really must some maths:
Using the wand above, camera fully zoomed out, at a resolution of 1920×1080, with screenshots taken as my shots are fading away at their full range, and using some crude approximate pixel measurements taken with Paint in Win 7, I reckon I'm seeing a rectangle of space approximately 24m×16m (completely ignoring the 3D perspective, etc) in size, which represents ~12m horizontally and ~8m vertically to the edges of the screen from the player character (in my case at least).

Comment: You'll also notice that your Torchlight 2 uses grid-based movement across the terrain (try clicking at your characters feet to understand the boundary of the grids). It would be nice to compare the measurements above with this grid to work out whether the grid is based on 1m or 0.5m square plots.

Comment: You can also stand a ways from the training dummy, and hold CTRL while attacking it.  Your character will move within range to attack, so this will give you a visual of how far 7.2 meters is, or whatever your attack range is.